# WooCommerce - Recent Products Offset

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Background:** WooCommerce provides a shortcode to display recent products any place I want.

```
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[recent_products columns="3"]'); ?>
```

There is an argument in **WP_Query** named **offset** that allows us to pass over desired number posts.

```
  <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'offset' => 3 ) ); ?>
```

So, if I use the above query to loop over posts, the first result I'd get would be the fourth latest post. Right?

**Question:** I was wondering if it would be possible to extend WC's Recent Posts shortcode to accept offset argument?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php` the `recent_products()` method like that:

```
public static function recent_products( $atts ) {
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'date',
            'order'    => 'desc',
            'offset'   => 0,
            'category' => '',  // Slugs
            'operator' => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ), $atts );
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
            'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],
            'offset'              => $atts['offset'],
            'meta_query'          => WC()->query->get_meta_query()
        );
        $query_args = self::_maybe_add_category_args( $query_args, $atts['category'], $atts['operator'] );
        return self::product_loop( $query_args, $atts, 'recent_products' );
    }
```

With this an `offset` attribute is added (default 0) that will be used in WP_Query.

Comment: It seems like a gentle solution. I wasn't able to locate the shortcodes-init.php file. Or is it a file that I'll have to create? Sorry for bothering but I am no good with WooCommerce.

Comment: Sorry this was from an older version. Look at the updated answer.

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to do it without changing the plugin itself? Because the change would go after the next update. Right?

Comment: @Symbolwdd Yes that's the issue. The better way to go would be to duplicate the shortcode in your own functions.php, in order to create your own shortcode. You'll have to extract the code from `product_loop` and `_maybe_add_category_args` as they are private methods, incorporate them in your function that you'll attach to `add_shortcode`. It's a bit of work but doable.